# Computing the integral $\int_{1}^{\infty} \sqrt{x}(1-e^{x^{-2}}) \; dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am currently working through previous exam questions and one of them says to
compute the integral $\int_{1}^{\infty} \sqrt{x}(1-e^{x^{-2}}) \; dx$ as a convergent series of real numbers. I have no idea how to even start, could I get some help?

Comment: Not that I think I can help, but do you mean: $e^{\frac{1}{x^2}}$?  I think that's the only thing that makes sense since if it were $\left(e^{x}\right)^{-2}$ then it would simply be $e^{-2x}$ (also clearly that second function would diverge).

Comment: It is $e^{\frac{1}{x^2}}$, which is why I didn't add the parenthesis

Comment: For $ x\ge1$, you can use the series expansion: $e^{1/x^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(1/x^2)^n}{n!}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, we may substitute $z=\frac{1}{x}$ to get:
$$ I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-e^{z^2}}{z^2\sqrt{z}}\,dz\tag{1} $$
then by writing $e^{z^2}$ as a Taylor series we get:
$$ I = -\sum_{n\geq 1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{z^{2n-\frac{5}{2}}}{n!}\,dz = \color{red}{-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2}{(4n-3)n!}}.\tag{2}$$

Comment: Great, thanks!!

Comment: Good thing the sum starts at 1 instead of 0.

Comment: @martycohen: sure, that $1-$ is essential, otherwise the integrand function of $(1)$ would have a non-integrable singularity in a right neighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: Hi Jack ! I have a problem. Could you check my answer, please and comment ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My result differs from  Jack D'Aurizio's answer.

Considering $$I=\int_1^\infty\sqrt{x}\left(1-e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\right)\,dx $$ changing variable $$x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\implies dx=-\frac{dt}{2 t^{3/2}}$$ leads to $$I=\frac 12 \int_0^1 \frac{1-e^{-t}}{t^{7/4}}\,dt$$ and expanding the exponential term as a Taylor series, I arrive to $$I=-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(4n-3)n!}\approx 1.83149$$ which coincides with the result of the numerical integration.

In fact this summation is exactly $$-\frac{2}{3}+\frac{2}{3 e}+\frac{2 \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{3}-\frac{2
   \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4},1\right)}{3}$$ which is confirmed by the fact that
$$\int\sqrt{x}\left(1-e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\right)\,dx=\frac{2
   \left(E_{\frac{3}{4}}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)+\left(1-e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\right
   ) x^2\right)}{3 \sqrt{x}} $$ where appears the exponential integral function.

It seems that we just differ by the $(-1)^n$ in the summation.

It must be noticed that the original function is always positive and the area under the curve must be positive.